# VCAP first-time startup issues

Tags: ruby, startup, runtime-error, eventmachine, cloud-foundry

Ok, so followed the steps outlined HERE to set up a VCAP instance. I ran it on freshly provisioned Ubuntu 10.04 cloud AMI from Ubuntu DIRECTLY (so its vanilla). After taking FOREVER, i got a success message and promptly tried to start the instance with the start command given in the instructions. When i run it, i get the following:

```
Targeting deployment "devbox" with cloudfoundry home "/home/vcap/cloudfoundry"
Setting up cloud controller environment
Setting up the uaa environment
Using cloudfoundry config from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config
Executing /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap start cloud_controller mongodb_node health_manager rabbitmq_node mongodb_gateway mysql_node redis_gateway uaa vblob_node filesystem_gateway mysql_gateway vblob_gateway stager dea rabbitmq_gateway postgresql_gateway router redis_node postgresql_node -c /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config -v /home/vcap/cloudfoundry -l /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/log
/home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate nats-0.4.28, because eventmachine-1.0.0 conflicts with eventmachine (= 0.12.10) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/vcap/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap:13:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Quite frankly, this error has me baffled...

Comment: NOTE: I have tried uninstalling all but one of the eventmachine gems and still, pieces fail to start. I get a lot od 'failed to register with cloud controller' and 'authorization with nats required' in the og files. The only piece that starts is the cloud controller after I 'fix' the eventmachne conflicts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a gem conflict which was addressed about an hour ago, for further information on this issue take a look at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/commit/8a513847518f5d4bedc314bcc52b372763d6de3e

Comment: Awesome! I noticed the fix and I am installing again! Ill let you know if it fixes the issue.